# How to create Ubuntu Applications

Tags: package-management, python, software-center, application-development

What should I use to create apps for the Ubuntu Software center? I have Ubuntu 16.04 and qtCreator keeps crashing for me (even 4.3.0). I can't find a good place to start for creating apps for the ubuntu software center. Can someone give me a good reference? Most references I've found are outdated because they use Quickly or qtcreator. I'm trying to code in python and haven't really been able to understand how the code -> packaging -> Ubuntu Software Center transition works. I'm not trying to create a web app but rather a stand alone executable, kind of like this [hello world example](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html), but in Python.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try pybuild? https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Pybuild

Comment: @user535733 I will go ahead and try that. I also came across the thought of using cx_freeze to just create exe but I'm not sure if those can be uploaded to the software center. Can only .deb files and snaps be uploaded to the software center?